# developing privileged apps in firefox os

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, manifest, mozilla, firefox-os

Java script works in the basic permission mode.
when changed to privileged mode, JavaScript does not work.

I found in a post that it does not work on an actual device, but works in the simulator.
But I am trying it in the simulator.

As a matter of fact I got it working once and the contacts API worked for me. It threw an exception once, and after that JavaScript does not work if I specify type as privileged.
Setting it as certified does not help.

Any help  please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you link your code?

Answer (score 0):

Abilash, I'll go through a quick explanation of the app permissions and privileges.

As can be found on [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Security/Security_model), please take a look at this:

[image: Trusted and Untrusted Apps]

They way it works, is that Certified apps are meant only for those apps who are embedded to the platform, and privileged apps have to go through the whole marketplace process. Some operations, such as network access, are assumed to be an implicit permission for all apps. In general, the more sensitive the operation (for example, dialing a phone number or accessing the Contacts list), the higher the app trust level required to execute it.

You might want to take a deeper look at the MDN link I provided above to understand how Privileges and Permissions works. MDN is fantastic when it comes to Firefox OS questions!

Please, feel free to ask more questions if they appear. I'll leave you with some boilerplate apps that might help you understand more about those. Here they [are](https://github.com/robnyman/Firefox-OS-Boilerplate-App)